# jQuery datatable table inside table causing mData undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

In one of my projects I am using datatables. This is one column structure in my table which is causing an error:

```
<th>
    <table class="table table-bordered table-condesed">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th colspan="7" class="text-center">Day Run</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>M</td>
                <td>T</td>
                <td>W</td>
                <td>T</td>
                <td>F</td>
                <td>S</td>
                <td>S</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</th>
```

Also this is the respective column:

```
<td>
    <table class="table table-bordered">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td tabindex="0">N</td>
                <td>N</td>
                <td>N</td>
                <td>N</td>
                <td>N</td>
                <td>N</td>
                <td>Y</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</td>
```

I don't know why but this is throwing an error when initialized. This is the error I am facing.

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'mData' of undefined`

I don't see anything wrong here. Any idea why its does not work?

Here is the live demo [Demo](http://indiaruler.net/trains-between-stations/ahmedabad-jn-to-mumbai-central/ADI-BCT)

Comment: Put the jquery code to initialize the datatable to?

Comment: @MayankPandeyz ye dekhiye bhai.. `$('.table').dataTable({searching: false, paging: false, responsive: true});
`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you are initializing `datatable` by using `class` like:

```
$('.table').dataTable({searching: false, paging: false, responsive: true});
```

and the column definition are different for both the table, I think this is the issue.

Do one thing, provide different `id` to both the table and initiate `datatable` with those `id's`